# Simple file downloader

Tags: php, security

On my website I want to offer some PDFs, ZIP files and images for download. They are all in the same folder and I could simply link to them like `<a href="download/file.pdf">download file</a>`. But instead I want to invoke a download dialog by sending an attachment header via php. The link would change into `<a href="download/load.php?f=file.pdf">download file</a>`:

```
<?php
/***
 * download/load.php
 * Simple file downloader including mime type
 *
 * @param string $f  name of file in download folder
 * @return file with corresponding HTTP header
 */

// check whether parameter was sent
if ( !isset($_GET['f']) ||
// check whether it is not `load.php` (this file)
     $_GET['f'] === "load.php" ||
// check whether file exists
     !is_readable($_GET['f']) ||
// make sure file is in the current directory
     strpos($_GET['f'], '/') ) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die();
}

$file = $_GET['f'];

// check mime type
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
finfo_close($finfo);

// send mime type
header('Content-type: ' . $mime);

// invoke download dialog
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file);

// send file
readfile($file);
?>
```

Is this script okay or does it have security vulnerabilities? If so, how could I improve it?

Comment: what happen if you try to change the ?f=X param? It allows you to download your application files?

Comment: Good point – except `load.php` there are no application files. But this one is downloadable. Not sure if it hurts. I'll edit the file anyway…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care to call `strpos()` correctly. If the `f` parameter contains a leading `/`, it sneaks through.

Comment: He does check if the filename given doesn't contain `/`. Although I'm not sure that's enough.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Fair enough. The initial `/` sneaks through, though, due to careless use of the tricky `strpos()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the file: `strpos($_GET['f'], '/') !== false`

Comment: Edit rolled back. Please do not edit code in the question in a way that invalidates an answer.